# How to kill a process I ran from a disconnected ssh

Tags: bash, unix, centos, kill

I logged in to a server using ssh and ran a long running process (load table from mysql dump file). The ssh connection got disconnected, and now when I'm connecting again the `jobs` command doesn't show this process (although it is still running). How is it still possible to kill this process?

Comment: a good tip.
if your working alot on an unstable ssh connection, try install screen, and work inside a screen session, this will continue your work, if you loose connection, and you can reconnect to the screen, if you need to.

Comment: I'm surprised your process is still running, as disconnecting from a session should kill any processes that haven't been disowned with `nohup`. Are you sure your mysql client process is still running? It might just be the server process processing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ps x
```

to list all your processes. The `x` option means to include processes without a controlling terminal, so it will include disconnected processes. Then use:

```
kill PID
```

to kill it.

You could also do:

```
killall PROGRAM
```

to kill it by the name of the program.

If the MySQL client process is gone, but the server process is still running, you can kill that from `mysql`:

```
mysql>show processlist; # Find the connection ID in this list
mysql>kill CONNECTIONID;
```

Comment: if the program ignores killall PROGRAM, try killall -9 PROGRAM
however this might do bad things to your databases, if its working on them.

Comment: That's somewhat orthogonal, since he'd have the same issue without getting disconnected.

Comment: I did `ps x` and this specific job wasn't there. When I ran it, and now I was logged in as root. Any idea why? The job itself looked like `mysql -u ... -p ... < file`

Comment: If you're logged in as the same user, and `ps x` doesn't show it, then it's not still running. It could be what I said in my comment above: the client is gone but the server is still processing the query it sent before it was killed.

Comment: @Barmar I see. It's still weird because the dump file is built from many `INSERT INTO` commands one after the other, and normally when I'm connected and kill the job, it stops processing it. And now I'm still seeing (it has been hours) the inserts are still being processed one after the other. No other way to stop this?

Comment: @Barmar well because the dump file is automatically built from a long list of independent `INSERT INTO` that only kills the current one that is being processed, leaving the others to still keep running.

Comment: I think it should work. All the statements are sent on the same connection. If you kill the connection, all the buffered statements are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start your long-running process with:

```
ssh 'user@server' './long-running-process.sh'
```

> In that case, SSH did not start a terminal for your long running
>   process. When the remote process does not have a controlling terminal,
>   the remote ssh process handling your session is unable to kill the
>   command. You can get around this by running it with a `-t` option,
>   which gives it a controlling terminal.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39638/40346 and https://superuser.com/a/20708/149568.

Answer (score 0):

What about using htop?

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

when you run htop from the command line, you will be able to see the processes and you will be able to arrange the processes by memory usage and cpu usage. pick the pid and kill it by pressing k then entering the process number.
If for any reason, you can not login to the server, because of overload, you can run the kill command without logging in. For example, if you want to kill firefox you can do

```
ssh 'user@server 'killall firefox'
```

That could be a lifesaver sometimes :)

Comment: when you can't login because of server overload this actually works? shouldn't this also timeout because of overload?

Comment: That actually works. I used it several times, this comes very handy when server for some reason runs out of storage space.